# Visio Shape Ungluing on Resize

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have two text blocks in Visio 2010, the one on bottom has an outgoing glue point on the top center of the shape, and the top shape has an incoming glue point on the bottom center.  I glue the shapes together, then when I resize the bottom shape, the glue gets broken.

Is there any way to not have the glue connection get broken when resizing the bottom shape?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better to have your two shapes within a group, the top edge of the lower shape can easily refer to the bottom edge of the upper shape, and the formulae can be guarded.
I have a shape you can download in:
http://www.sandrila.co.uk/visio-sdl/
Download the zip file and extract the **Object model** stencil. Look at shape **Object**. That shape might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it needs to work in a pretty generic manner, allowing users to glue any combination of shapes together.